# Button to pass text from a text box into href call in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, href

I'm trying to allow a user to click a button which then takes the value inside a textbox and adds it to the end of an href call. I currently have a function that adds the two strings together and calls the href but when the button is clicked, nothing seems to happen. Here's what I got so far:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>

function findAccountID() {
  var text = document.getElementById('textInput');
  var value = encodeURIComponent(text.value); //encode special characters
  location.href = '**href path here**'+value; //goto URL
}

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="textInput" />
      <input type="button" value="Find Account ID" onclick="findAccountID();" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add slash `/` between location.href & value
In the following snippet the `newHref` variable is concatenation of 
`location.href` & textbox value. If you intend to navigate to new url set `location.href` to this `newHref`

```js
function findAccountID() {
  var text = document.getElementById('textInput');
  var value = encodeURIComponent(text.value); //encode special characters
  let newHref = location.href + '/' + value
  console.log(newHref)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="textInput" />
  <input type="button" value="Find Account ID" onclick="findAccountID();" />
</div>
```